# css [display:-webkit-box;] made my [opacity:0.3;] invalid

Tags: css

I have a span with [display:-webkit-box;] in an ant-design-vue-table item. When I try to use [opacity:0.3] in "tr", it's looks ok. But when I try to use [opacity:0.3] in the "-webkit-box 's father box", the opacity doesn't work. And when I don't use the [display:-webkit-box;] it's all ok.
I'm confused if I did something wrong?
here are the photos:

[But when I try to use [opacity:0.3] in the "-webkit-box 's father box", the opacity doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5FaN.png)

[When I try to use [opacity:0.3] in "tr", it's looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oh9v.png)

[And when I don't use the [display:-webkit-box;] it's all ok.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKQM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the way the first selector is expressed.

```
[data-v-39bbd7fb] .row-gray .gray-item
```

A couple of points:

- .row-gray is nowhere that I can see in that element. It should not be
  part of the selector
- remember that a space character has significance in a CSS selector. See for example [MDN](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/...):

> The descendant combinator — typically represented by a single space ( ) character — combines two selectors such that elements matched by the second selector are selected if they have an ancestor (parent, parent's parent, parent's parent's parent, etc) element matching the first selector. Selectors that utilize a descendant combinator are called descendant selectors.

Therefore try this:
`[data-v-39bbd7fb].gray-item` - remember, no spaces as the attribute and the class are within the same element tag.